# .Net Core Dependency Injection in Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, console-application

I am trying to use dependency injection in a .NET Core Console App.
There are a lot of articles about it, but did not find one that fixes my problem.
I am trying to use services original from an aspnet core web app, thats why i have the WebHost.

My main problem is to create an instance of my own class, all the dependency seems to work, and my console app starts up.

I have this code in my Program class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    var services = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging();            
    var container = new Container();           
    var serviceProvider = container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
```

This code will not compile due to this error:
'Container' does not contain a definition for 'GetInstance'

How can i create an instance of my custom class App which has this implementation:

```
public class App
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public App(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to create your own `ServiceCollection` or `ServiceProvider` in this scenario - You can just use the `IWebHost`'s [`Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost.services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHost_Services) property that you already have:

```
var app = host.Services.GetService<App>();
```

`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` already adds the logging services, so there's no need to do that either.

Note: I'm assuming that you've registered your `App` and `IProductService` types in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.

Comment: on .NET 6.0.100 ServiceCollection has been moved to the Abstractions lib - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll  -adding reference to that lib causes the following error:  

The type 'ServiceCollection' exists in both 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'  

Adding Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 6.0.0.0 explicitly doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @Zirc75 It looks like you have references to both 5.0 and 6.0, which isn't right and would explain the error you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what a "Container" is in your setting, but you normally create a service provider by calling [`BuildServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on the `ServiceCollection`.

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var instance = provider.GetService<App>();
```

You will need to register both `App` and whatever `IProductService` you want with the services collection first though.